# How can I plug my MacBook Pro 2019 to my monitor and get 144hz safely

Tags: macbook-pro

I own a late 2019 16 inch Macbook Pro. For medical reasons I need to plug a monitor to it so I stop looking down all the time. I own an old BenQ monitor, but has Hdmi, capped to 60hz, DVI that goes up to 144hz and and a VGA port (Model is XL2411).

I have no idea how to plug it to my macbook so that I can have up to 144hz. I also heard that some cables can cause your Macbook pro to die, so I'm kinda scared and would appreciate any help !

Comment: Or a remote keyboard and mouse with the laptop on a stand?

Comment: The screen is already pretty small for my eyes, doing that I have to put it even further, plus capped to 60hz ! :D
Also stands would be difficult to ship, so I'd rather some sort of adapter if that exists ?

Comment: The MBP 16" 2019 specs say up to 60Hz refresh. I can't see 144Hz working.

Comment: @Gilby , is that not just 60Hz for the internal panel?

Comment: @LillyCham The specs say 60Hz for external. Maybe it can be made to work at higher speed with DisplayPort 1.4 - but my understanding (no direct experience) is only with M1 MBP.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't believe that tells me how to plug it in to my monitor.

Comment: …but it does tell you you cannot do 144Hz.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is weird because I have read on forums people getting way more than 60 fps on their external screens...

Comment: Render fps is not in any way related to screen refresh rate. Many gamers are unaware of this & spend their time trying to increase fps to truly pointless levels, whilst never realising they will never actually see it.

Answer (score -1):

Your best option with that monitor is a USB-C (Thunderbolt 3) to DisplayPort cable. It is safe and should give you an option for 144hz if your GPU and macOS version support it.

Comment: That monitor doesn't have display port. Only DVI, Hdmi and VGA.

Comment: I looked up the wrong variant of this model, my bad